# Sulu 2.0: How to access the seo description from search hit?

Tags: sulu

We are trying to display the meta description field of a document on our search results page. It looks like it is quite hidden in the system, but probably easy if one knows how to get actual extension data.

A search hit has this fields:

```
Massive\Bundle\SearchBundle\Search\QueryHit
  #document: Sulu\Bundle\SearchBundle\Search\Document
  #score: 0.38863644103659
  #id: "af9683db-f9f8-4cee-a784-c384019150e8"
}
```

I can use the `sulu_document_manager.document_manager` service to get the corresponding PageDocument for the Id, which in turn seems to have access to the extension data:

```php
/** @var PageDocument $document */
$document = $this->documentManager->find($id);
```

But how to actually get access to the concrete value `descripion` of the seo extension? Is this even the right way to do it, or should I use a different approach?

Thx a lot!
Andreas

Answer (score 1):

This is one possibility to get the excerpt - from the document you can access `$document->getExtensions()['excerpt']` the excerpt data.

But the better way is to use the QueryHit `$queryHit->getDocument()->getField('excerptDescription')->getValue()`. See the query-hit document itself to see which fields are available by default.

Comment: Awesome, thx a lot! I'll validate this in the code and accept the answer once I made it work :)

Comment: Ok, so I finally found the time to have a look and `$queryHit->getDocument()->getField('excerptDescription')->getValue()` seems not to return the actual seo description, also all the extensiondata does not get pupulated. I fixed now by the rather hacky direct access via the node manager: `$this->nodeManager->find($queryHit->getId())->getPropertyValue('i18n:de-seo-description')`